# Move a single collection in Firebase Cloud Firestore from one project to another

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have two Firebase projects, one for `dev` and another for `production`. The collections in `dev` are first tested and then moved to `production` if the tests succeed. How can I move collections between Firestore databases without using [`Cloud Shell`  method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data)? Are there any alternative databases that can achieve this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63330076/17627866

Answer (score 1):

If you have a relatively small database, you can get away without using cloud shells or  cloud buckets.

The Firebase SDK allows you create [multiple apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-multiple-apps) at the same time, each with their own configuration information. This means that you can write a program that reads data from one database and writes it to another database.

In Python, to transfer all documents in `some-collection` found in `dev` to `destination-collection` found in `prod`:

```py
dev_cred = ... # credentials for dev
default_app = initialize_app(dev_cred)
dev_db = firestore.client(default_app)

prod_cred = ... # credentials for prod
other_app = initialize_app(prod_cred )
prod_db = firestore.client(other_app, name="other-app")

collection_ref = dev_db.collection(u'some_collection')
destination_collection_ref = prod_db.collection(u'destination-collection')

# transfer documents
for doc in collection_ref.stream():
    destination_collection_ref.document(doc.id).set(doc.to_dict())
```

This can be done in other programming languages as well. The above code can also be extended to transfer [subcollections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document).

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to move collections between your `dev` and your `production` databases, without using `Cloud Shell`, there is an alternative that you can follow.

For you to achieve that, you will need to follow the below steps.

1. Create a Cloud Storage bucket to hold the data from your source project.
2. Export the data from your source project to the bucket.
3. Give your destination project permission to read from the bucket.
4. Import the data from the bucket into your destination project.

With these steps, you should be able to migrate data between your projects and have this way, the structure you want of a Development database and a Production database, where you can easily transfer the data. I would recommend you to check the official documentation [Move Data Between Projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data), to get the whole tutorial on how to achieve the above steps, in case you have doubts on how to achieve them.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Answer (score -1):

You can export the collection using cloud shell

[Manage export ad import](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import)