# How to import all firestore documents from an export to a specific collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

So I want to be able to create a snapshot of the database as it is to create a "development" collection.

I am able to export all the data currently on firestore using the tutorial here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#export_data.

Firebase only shows how to import specific collections **from** that stored export.

How can I import the export **to** a specific "development" collection within firestore?

For example:

Cloud Firestore Database Collections (day 1)

- Users (as of day 1)

  - Has a document for each user
- Tasks (as of day 1)

  - Has a document for each task
- Chats (as of day 1)

  - Has a document for each chat

**->** export all this data to google cloud platform bucket
**->** import all the exported data into a “development” collection

Cloud Firestore Database Collections (day 2)

- Users (as of day 2)
- Tasks (as of day 2)
- Chats (as of day 2)
- Development

  - Users (as of day 1)
  - Tasks (as of day 1)
  - Chats (as of day 1)

I can then use this development collection as a database snapshot for testing, then the other collections can be used in production as normal.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking.  Could you illustrate with a specific example, and what you tried that doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: I've added an illustration to my answer

Comment: Please do not share pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such feature in Cloud SDK (using `gcloud firestore`) however it's quite easy to be done programmatic way. With two remarks:

1. Collection has to be in document, so construction collection "Users"
   in collection "Development" is not possible. However its possible to
   do "User" in document "Development" in collection "Development"
   (/Development/Development/Users etc.)
2. This will cost you reads and writes to Firestore, if you have big
   database it may cost both time and **money**. So be careful with that.

If you are OK with above it's quite easy. Here is a sample doing this thing to document "devDoc" in collection "devCol" in JS ([quickstart](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)):

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

devRefsegments = ["devCol","devDoc"];

db.listCollections().then(colList => {
    colList.forEach(colRef => 
        colRef.get().then(colSnap => {
            colSnap.forEach(prop => {
                var path = makepath(devRefsegments,prop._ref._path.segments);
                db.doc(path).set( prop.data()).then(r => console.log(r));
            });
        })
    );
});


function makepath(devRefsegments, segments) {
    return "/"+devRefsegments.join("/")+"/"+segments.join("/");
}
```

I am running this in GCP Cloud Shell, however you can easily make cloud function of this, if you want. And of course you can use other languages as well. I suggest to try on small db to avoid cost at start.

Comment: Thank you, that should work. I will make a cloud function!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same task to be done. I viewed a lot of articles. But i am explaining you the easiest possible way to do this task.

Suppose you have a database db_to_be_export in project db_to_be_export_project and you want to import the data of this database to another project's database called db_to_be_import_project. where the database name is db_to_be_import.

There are few steps to be followed

1. Download the private file of both the projects. you can download the file by following this instruction.
   Goto to the Firebase Console > Project Overview > Project Setting > Service Accounts > Generate New Private Key
2. Rename both the files. Set the name of the file from where we want to export data to "Export.json" and "Import.json" to the file where we want to import data.
3. Move both the files to a folder.
4. Open terminal in case of mac machine. Move to the directory where both the json files are present.
5. ```
   Now run this command "npx -p node-firestore-import-export firestore-export -a Export.json -b backup.json"
   ```
6. ```
   Now run this last command "npx -p node-firestore-import-export firestore-import -a Import.json -b backup.json"
   ```

Open the database "db_to_be_import" in the firestore console now can now see the complete data which is present in the database "db_to_be_export".